# Using xpcom with django

Tags: django, xpcom

I am usign xpcom objects with django. When i use development server everything works fine but when I switch to Apache server with mod_wsgi I get interface not found error.

I have searched a lot about the error, which says that the id is different then one you are using for the interface. But i havent changed anything, same code works for development server.

Comment: [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM) on the server? That would be extremely uncommon. Maybe you mean using Microsoft's COM? Please edit your answer and clarify.

Comment: What I am doing is, I am using xpcom apis for python in my django code which works fine with django development server. I have found on archived mail list where they discuss the same : http://www.mail-archive.com/mozilla-xpcom@mozilla.org/msg00622.html but this code is not available as you could test :)

Comment: Wow... I better don't ask why anybody would do that.